# "If" statement comparison operators sequence of operation

Tags: php

I have an "if" statement I would like to write with multiple comparison operators of the "&&" and "||" type. I am not entirely sure if it will perform the way I am thinking it should. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
if($alpha == "FF" && $bravo == "3sh" || $charlie == "6sh")
{
    printf($alpha);
}
```

What I expect is that $alpha MUST equal "FF" in order for this to execute.

What I also expect is at least one of the other two conditions must be met in order to execute.

What I am concerned about is the code ignoring the first two conditions and executing the code because the last condition is met.

Comment: Try this way `if($alpha == "FF" && ($bravo == "3sh" || $charlie == "6sh"))`

Comment: Ah! Yes, I knew there must have been something simple like that. I just couldn't remember it for whatever reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create wrap conditions accordingly as below:

```
if($alpha == "FF" && ($bravo == "3sh" || $charlie == "6sh"))
{
    printf($alpha);
}
```

So here, `$alpha == "FF"` should have to be true. And either one condition should be true in between on braces. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to look into Boolean logic a litte more, but for your particular situation what you are trying to do is:

```
if($alpha == "FF" && ($bravo == "3sh" || $charlie == "6sh"))
{
    printf($alpha);
}
```

Essentially, you say
`$alpha == "FF"` must be true AND
`($bravo == "3sh" || $charlie == "6sh")` must be true 
- i.e., either `$bravo == "3sh"` OR `$charlie == "6sh"`